# Помогите написать батчевский скрипт для запуска запросов

Tags: curl, bat

Есть метод api который проверяет по логину есть ли у пользователя доступ в систему. Есть список пользователей. Как можно курл запустить в цикле для списка пользователей?
curl -X GET "http://cas-auth.cas.prod.s.o3.ru/user/390833/logins" -H  "accept: text/plain" метод

Там где 390833, должны быть разные переменные

Comment: o_O `curl -X GET "http://cas-auth.cas.prod.s.o3.ru/user/%variable_name%/logins" -H "accept: text/plain"` либо `curl -X GET "http://cas-auth.cas.prod.s.o3.ru/user/%%variable_letter/logins" -H "accept: text/plain"` - зависит от типа переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть есть файл `users.dat` в котором в каждой строке записан идентификатор пользователя

```
390833
390835
390836
390837
```

Тогда можно написать файл `test.bat` в котором все эти идентификаторы будут проверены

```
for /f %%i in (users.dat) do curl -X GET "http://cas-auth.cas.prod.s.o3.ru/user/%%i/logins" -H "accept: text/plain"
```

Если же все идентификаторы идут последовательно с некоторым шагом, то можно вообще без дополнительного файла

```
rem Проверить идентификаторы от 390833 до 390837 с шагом 1
for /L %%i in (390833, 390837, 1) do curl -X GET "http://cas-auth.cas.prod.s.o3.ru/user/%%i/logins" -H "accept: text/plain"
```